# How to identify that last DOMSubtreeModified is fired?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

When i am using 'DOMSubtreeModified', i get multiple, sometimes 30+ events firing. Is it possible to ensure that my function is only called once last DOMSubtreeModified is fired?

Comment: You could create a throttle that only runs your function after a DOMSubtreeModified event hasn't happened in 50ms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation of Kevin B's mentioned throttle:

```
function throttle( fn, time ) {
    var t = 0;
    return function() {
        var args = arguments,
            ctx = this;

            clearTimeout(t);

        t = setTimeout( function() {
            fn.apply( ctx, args );
        }, time );
    };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", throttle( function() {
    //code
}, 50 ), false );
```

If at all possible, make your code independent of DOM mutation events as they're more evil than eval and with combined